# Initiate A Call To Multiple Numbers Simultaneously with Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to call multiple numbers at the same time right from the start, if someone pickup others will be automatically hang up.

The issue is I can only see that feature under TWIML>Dail and to use that feature you need to initiate a call first.

How do I initiate a call immediately to multiple parties?

I tried:

```
twilio_client.client.calls.create(
    twiml=twiml,
    to=["+10000000","+10000000"],
    from_="+10000000"
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path. Calls Per Second (CPS) is 1, so it will have to be increased if you require the calls go out at or around the same time.

You need to loop through that resource you documented and handle the logic to cancel the other calls if one answers.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Some services are dialing multiple numbers at once if the CPS is 1 why they mentioned this on their doc? ```This noun allows you to <Dial> another number while specifying additional behavior. Simultaneous dialing is also possible using multiple <Number> nouns.``` there must be another way to do it, maybe by using 2 phones to initiate the first call then dail the other numbers using the dail twiml, I had that on my mind but I thought it must be a simpler way to do it

Comment: Dial is as you said, when you are connecting an incoming call with an another party. You indicated you are initiating an outbound call.